# Conflict between cordova-plugin-firebasex and cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks IONIC 5

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic5, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I am getting this error when i am making build for ios in IONIC 5.

Installing "cordova-plugin-firebasex" for ios
Running command: pod install --verbose
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebasex': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1.

I already matched the firebase modules in plugin.xml files of firebase deeplink and analytics and firebasex plugin

```
<pods use-frameworks="true">
                <pod name="Firebase/Core" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/Auth" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/Messaging" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/Performance" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/RemoteConfig" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/InAppMessaging" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="FirebaseFirestore" git="https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git" tag="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/Crashlytics" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/Functions" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="Firebase/Installations" spec="8.4.0"/>
                <pod name="GoogleSignIn" spec="5.0.2"/>
                <pod name="GoogleTagManager" spec="7.3.1"/>
            </pods>
```

In the  firebase analytics plugin -

```
   <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="IOS_FIREBASE_POD_VERSION" default="8.4.0" />
<platform />
```

In the firebase dynamic link plugin -

```
   <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="IOS_FIREBASE_POD_VERSION" default="8.4.0" />
<platform />
```

when i run the pod update nothing happens.please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex#cocoapods

Comment: @MartinZeitler, after running pod repo update on project folder an then pod install on platforms/ios/ .i am geeting this error now.           Pre-downloading: 
    FirebaseInstallations (= 8.10.0, ~> 8.0)

  

Specs satisfying the `FirebaseInstallations (= 8.10.0, ~> 8.0), FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.0), FirebaseInstallations (~> 8.4.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late, but I am hopeful it would still be helpful to anyone looking for an answer.

After inspecting the `cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks` package. I have found the following dependency

> `<dependency id="cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" version="~6.0.0"/>`

This shows that the dynamic links package requires the analytics plugin dependency to work.

As the project is being built, the build process will try to fetch the analytics package for you and it would fail to do so as the package requires `Firebase Analytics ~> 8.2.0` by Default. If you inspect the pods as they are being installed, you can find that during the dynamic links fetching process, the analytics plugin will be fetched, and it would fail to install causing an issue.

Therefore, the solution would be to explicitly include the Firebase Analytics package as follows:

```
 "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
    "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "ANDROID_ICON_ACCENT": "#FF00FFFF",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_MONITORING": "true",
    "ANDROID_PLAY_SERVICES_AUTH_VERSION": "19.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "19.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_VERSION": "22.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CONFIG_VERSION": "21.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_VERSION": "20.0.2",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION": "21.0.1",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FIRESTORE_VERSION": "23.0.2",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_VERSION": "20.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_IID_VERSION": "21.1.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_INSTALLATIONS_VERSION": "17.0.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_VERSION": "18.1.0",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_NDK_VERSION": "18.1.0",
    "ANDROID_GSON_VERSION": "2.8.7",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_PERF_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION": "1.4.0"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": {
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "19.0.0",
    "IOS_FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_VERSION": "8.4.0",
    "ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
    "AUTOMATIC_SCREEN_REPORTING_ENABLED": "true"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks": {
    "APP_DOMAIN_NAME": "***",
    "ANDROID_FIREBASE_DYNAMICLINKS_VERSION": "20.0.0",
    "IOS_FIREBASE_DYNAMICLINKS_VERSION": "8.4.0",
    "APP_DOMAIN_PATH": "/"
  },
```

This will allow the iOS version of Analytics to be explicitly set alongside the version in the Dynamic Links.

Note: The ordering of the plugins in package.json can sometimes break the package fetching process.

This has worked in my case, and hopefully it would work out for you too.